# Replace any 2 characters between / and / with wildcard matching

Tags: php, string, replace

I have these strings `/re/` or `/en/` etc.

I'd like to replace everything inside / and / including the 2 `/`s, something like this:

```
str_replace("/??/", $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: I meant the beggining `/` and ending `/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably searching for [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
preg_replace("#/.{1,2}/#", $replacement, $string)
```

Comment: yea, it's almsot that, but I need to limit it on 2 characters

Comment: @simPod I changed the regex for you to do what you want (1 to 2 characters)

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_replace("{/../}", $replacement, $string);
```

This will replace all instances of any two characters surrounded by `/` with whatever the replacement you want is. If you know the contents will only ever be alphanumeric, then you could do `\w\w` instead of `..`.

If you need to apply it to strings of any length, then what others have recommended: "{/.+/}" would work.

Note, I'm using `{` and `}` instead of the more common `/` delimiters because they are valid, and because your matching string contains `/`. That way we don't need to escape the matched instances of `/` making it a little easier to read.

Comment: You forgot the delimiters: `{` and `}` don't match, so either `'{/../{'` or `}/../}` should be the pattern

Comment: They do not have to match exactly that way for certain delimiters. { and } are perfectly valid. Try it: `<? echo preg_match("{abc}","abcdefg"); ?>`

Comment: You can even use `[` and `]` and `(` and `)` as valid delimiters, though no one in their right mind would want to use those, given their prevalence in regexes (because you'll have to escape every valid instance of them, and things just start getting weird then). If the delimiter is symmetrical, it can be used symmetrically.

Comment: You're right... I wasn't sure, so I checked on [functions-online](http://www.functions-online.com), where I got an error. on [writecodeonline](http://writecodeonline.com/php) it did work, though

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$in = 'foo/ba/r and /so/me';
$out = preg_replace('/\/[^\/]{2}\//','/REPLACEMENT/',$in);
echo $out;//'foo/REPLACEMENT/r and /REPLACEMENT/me'
```

Basically, the regex matches any (sub)-string that is delimited by forward slashes, and contains two (and only two) characters except for forward slashes. So `/s//` won't be matched, but `/ss/` will

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '/rr/';
$replacement = 'a';
echo preg_replace("#/\w{2}/#", $replacement, $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('~/[a-z]{2}/~', $replacement, $string);
```